# Не получается добавить видео на страницу

Tags: html, css, видео, page

сделал блок с классом

```
`<div id="video">
<div class="Vid">
    <iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="1px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
'
```

в css

```
div.vid{
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;

}

div.vid iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

В итоге на странице отображается только frameborder="1px" а содержимое внутри не показывает. В чем может быть проблема что я делаю не так?=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я для этого использую такую конструкцию:

```css
.div1 {
  padding-top: 5px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: relative; 
  max-width: 640px;
}

.div2 {
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: relative; 
  height: 0px; 
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.iframe {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0px; 
  top: 0px; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <iframe class="iframe" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fpTUIoxNpYw?wmode=transparent&amp;controls=2" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тут https://jsfiddle.net/m0wg57q3/ можно ширину изменить и посмотреть на изменение видео.

Comment: Спасибо!=) получилось наконец=)

Comment: А если на сайте картинка как фон, поверх картинки надпись по центру, размещаю видео поверх картинки, но надпись в одном браузере улетает далеко вправо, а в другом-мелькает и как будто скрыта под видео. Что может быть?